# In what order are catnip bonuses applied?

Tags: kittens-game

I'm trying to determine how my farmers factor into my bonuses, and I just can't make the math work out.

Is there an easy way to calculate what my catnip production will be given the following factors?

- Number of fields
- Number of aquaducts
- Whether or not you have mineral or iron hoes
- Karma/paragon bonuses

I know these are various +x or *1.x or whatever, but I'm having trouble nailing down where the parentheses would go - which of these stack multiplicatively, additively, etc.

What is the master catnip production formula?

Answer (score 2):

This is the general resource production formula, taken from the [FAQ](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Resources&redirect=no):

```
perTick = (building output * season modifier + job output * upgrades * happiness) * building % effects + automatic effects - consumption * consumption % effects
```

Comment: And remember to apply the order of operations correctly: PEMDAS